# "There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, here's an example showing so" - is this a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Unfortunately the post I have in mind has been edited to the point where it wouldn't make sense, but take this situation:

A question is asked of the style "I'm having a problem with this code, this is the error I get" with a code sample.

An answer is posted of "there's nothing wrong with this particular code sample you posted, you should look elsewhere if you're having problems" with a new included code sample demonstrating the fact that there's nothing wrong with it.

Is this an acceptable answer, or is this something that should be just a comment?

Comment: [Are "works for me" answers valid?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: @Squint, I contest that 'works for me' is not the same as 'works for me and here's how you can be sure of it' in terms of overall usefulness.

Comment: Read the question. It's the same. You said it works, and provided a demonstration showing that it works. This does nothing to help the OP with the actual issue, unless you actually think they're lying and have nothing better to do than to deceitfully post bogus questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This site is riddled with questions where the actual problem is not really present in the code.

Because of this, we have a bunch of comments which are either asking for "the real code" or asking for other parts of the code (`where is x instantiated?`)

Telling someone that you've copied their code and it works is effectively one of those comments, and it should be posted as a comment.

Comment: I am then perhaps a tad too literal about what an 'answer' is :)