# A "Works for me answer" flagged as Not an answer was declined, is that a valid declination?

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I just got my flag declined on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22170580/1864167).

This answer is nothing more than a request for clarification combined with a "Works for me, though!" and should not be considered a valid answer.

Was this a matter of a missclick or is there a factor I didn't consider?

Usually I would follow this up with a custom flag but I have none left and there doesn't seem to be a mod looking at the tavern.

Comment: The user even states that they answered because they lacked the reputation to comment. I don't think your flag should have been declined.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That looks like a probable mis-click by the mod who declined the flag. That's definitely a request for feedback, so your flags were correct. I converted that answer to a comment. Sorry about the mix-up.

Comment: Problem solved then, thanks for looking at it. I'll have to be particularly careful in the next 100 flags so I don't go over my 1% failure treshold.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Your "declined" rate just shot up from 1.06% to 1.13%. Sorry about that. Still, not too shabby. :)

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: 17%. I do a lot of "invalid flag" flags.

Comment: I *meant* to decline those flags.  I took it as an answer; "I tried your code, and it worked fine. Why do you need to convert your data?"

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I don't see how that is an answer considering nothing gets solved by this. If the code works then it must be an environmental issue which should be pinpoint through comments and not asked for clarification in the answer section. I base myself on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I guess it's debatable whether that's an answer or not. If it had some kind of [Lang]Fiddle link that showed that the code worked I'd probably accept it as an answer, but as it stands it reads more like a request for feedback.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The last line is especially important. "We do occasionally disagree.".  "My code is broken." Answer: "No it isn't." That's an answer -- it's not the answer the user wanted to hear, but it is an answer.  I'll go half-sies with you next time and mark it 'helpful', but not delete the answer. How's that?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I'm not *that* attached to that ratio ;) Ideally it would be great if the mods could come to an agreement on how to handle this so we would know how to handle the flags. Your solution is a good middle ground, ofcourse.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It all evens out in the wash. Keeps everyone on their toes and keeps flagging from becoming robo-flagging, or worse SEDE-Flagging.

Comment: One more [mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166096/verification-of-precipitation-forecast-r-package/22170580#22170580) was happened by you only yesterday :)